# Caret position with VSCode's Vim going after a word and not before

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

I just downloaded the Vim extension from VSCode and I've got a simple problem but which is quite annoying (probably related to the fact that I'm still getting started).

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
^
```

I have my caret onto the first character `L` and I press `e` to go to the end of `Lorem`. (use case to add something add the end of a line).

If I then press `i` to enter Insert Mode, my caret goes before the `m` of `Lorem` and not after. This is quite annoying because I cannot easily append text at the end of the line.

Am I using Vim right ?

Thanks for your clarifications!

Comment: This is correct vim behaviour, you can double check this in vim. What you want is to press `a` in normal mode to have the cursor go after the current character into insert mode.

Comment: Oh I get it now ! Then what's the use case for typing one letter before the end ?

Comment: vim is all about composition of functionality to do useful things.its the philosophy behind its use. in this sense, the `e` functionality and `i` vs `a` functionality are simply distinct, well-defined tools that are available to the user. how the user chooses to compose these do to something 'useful' is completely up to them. 

note: vim has a detailed help system that is indispensible when you are learning to use the editor. checkout help on any keystroke or functionality with `:h e<CR>` or `:h i<CR>` in normal mode for example (`<CR>` means carriage return, colloquially known as 'enter'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour of `i`, which is used to insert text *before* the cursor. If you want to insert text *after* the cursor, the right command is `a`. If you want to insert text *at* the cursor, the right command is `s`.

> Am I using Vim right ?

You are not using Vim at all, which, at least partially, explains why you are annoyed by a very normal and expected behaviour.

Learning Vim with Vim emulators in regular editors/IDEs is a bad idea for several reasons:

- They are not Vim so their behaviour is pretty much guaranteed to deviate from Vim's in one way or another. They may miss Vim features, or be opinionated about what to add and how to implement it, etc.. All things that will cause confusion down the line.
- They all implement slightly different subsets of Vim in slightly different ways so using one Vim emulator in one IDE and another one in another IDE won't get you the same experience.
- They tend to fall back to the host's own features when they are considered more convenient than Vim's, which will inevitably create false expectations, on one hand, and hide truly useful Vim features.
- They are mostly designed with actual Vim users in mind, as a way to ease the transition to whatever the host editor/IDE is. You are not a Vim user so you are not in the target demographic.
- Vim is a beast. In order to use it efficiently, there are lots and lots of things you will have to unlearn and lots of things you will have to learn. Thankfully, Vim comes with an incredible built-in documentation, including a very thorough and gently iterative tutorial, `:help user-manual` that will painlessly take you from noob to pro. Vim emulators don't have anything that comes close to that so users are left to their own devices, trying random stuff they find online, building false assumptions and so on.

  Case in point, VSCodeVim doesn't have `:help`, which, in Vim, could have been used to see what's up with `i`.

  Learning Vim in Vim is the only strategy that makes sense.

Here is a suggested approach:

1. If you didn't already, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to get the basics right.
2. As instructed at the end of vimtutor, level up to the user manual `:help user-manual`. It will guide you progressively through *every* feature, from basic to advanced. This not a novel, go at your own pace, skip chapters, come back to them later, and, most importantly, experiment along the way.
3. Keep an eye on anti-patterns and inefficient actions, find improvements, practice. Rinse. Repeat.